# How to modify the scroll bar style of <embed> tag

Tags: css, iframe, frontend, scrollbar, embed

for example,`<embed src="xxx.pdf"></embed>` or `<iframe src="xxx.pdf"></iframe>`. I want to modify the scrollbar style in embed
or pdf. embed::-webkit-scrollbar, embed::-webkit-scrollbar-track, embed::-webkit-scroll-thumb is invalid.

Comment: My suggestion would be: don't! Browser scrollbar aren't so nice but not really easy functionalities or properties to change them. There are tricks but you will have always and often problems with user configuration: browsers, setting of browser, computer... which breaks your very nice scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate answer to duplicate question until closed see [Making a scrollable div that encompasses the entire height of the PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56279786/making-a-scrollable-div-that-encompasses-the-entire-height-of-the-pdf/73911188?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C11.1778#73911188)

The scrollbars in the pdf viewer are controlled INSIDE the viewer not from outside so here I can switch toolbar or scrollbars on and off by pressing keys but browsers do not permit external programable entries inside a pdf workspace. The instructions must be from the pdf internal script As done by setting inside Acrobat PDFs OR it must be either user or their program inside the binary viewer

[image]

Comment: Can I bind scrolling events to PDF? I need to judge whether the user has finished reading PDF